# Script at specified location: failed to close STDERR

Tags: linux, shell, sh, aws-code-deploy, nohup

I have a script that gets the following error:

**Error**

> InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at
> specified location: scripts/powwow-deploy.sh failed to close STDERR
>
> Script at specified location: scripts/powwow-deploy.sh failed to close
> STDERR

**powwow-deploy.sh**

```
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar > logs/nohup.out &
```

I think the problem is because I am writing the output to `nohup.out`, i.e. `> logs/nohup.out`.

How can I make it write to `logs/nohup.out` without getting the error?

Comment: BTW, there's no good reason for you to use `nohup` here (or, I might argue, anywhere else) at all. If you redirect all three of stdin, stdout and stderr (so `</dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1`) and are running your code noninteractively, the HUP handling that nohup enforces is the same thing the shell would do by default regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>logs/nohup.out` redirects STDOUT. But you also want to redirect STDERR. You could add `2>&1` to send both STDOUT and STDERR to `logs/nohup.out`.